# What loopInvariant I should use?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble doing loop_invariant this cycle:

```
int count= 0;
//@ loop_invariant (\forall int i; 0<=i && i<size; i%2*dim == target;
//@ decreases size-i;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
if (i%2*dim == target)
    count++;
return count;
```

Basically I want to count the number of times that a position is accessed in a vector.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you trying to find the number of times each individual item is accessed? For example; element1 accessed 2 times,element2 accessed 4 time etc?

Comment: One thing is sure: `i%2*dim == target` can't be a loop invariant; otherwise you wouldn't have to test for it.

Comment: Second thing, `i%2*dim == target` resolves either to `target == 0` or `target == dim` so the whole calculation seems like an overkill.

Comment: I think this gives the same result with no loops: `return dim == target? 1+size/2 : 0;`

Comment: Thanks for your awnser.
I want this:

My positions Vectores: (dim == 7 %% arr.length==14)
[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13]

What I want is:

Count the number of times I passed a position.
For example, I want to start counting at position 2 the times spent in the 5 position with size == 10.
The result is 1.